# Unxpected result of Number(Number) + Number(String)

Tags: actionscript-3, numbers

I can't figure out why is it so:

```
var a:String = "0.07";
var b:Number = 0.08;
trace( Number(a) + Number(b) ); // 0.15000000000000002
```

, but when using tenths, results are ok:

```
var a:String = "0.7";
var b:Number = 0.8;
trace( Number(a) + Number(b) ); // 1.5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: Welcome to floating point arithmetic. This has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript) for JavaScript already and the same ideas apply to as3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies between using `Number` which is a **float** type (not **integer** type). Floating point arithmetic is **imprecise** and usually rounded to give what appears to be correct value. For example `0.08 + 0.08` gives correct **0.16** and so does `0.07 + 0.07` giving correct **0.14**, so why does `0.07 + 0.08` not give correct **0.15**? A **Float Rounding Error** gives you that **0.15000000000000002** result.

Remember`trace` shows Strings (which can hold all the digits) so you get the system printing out the full **0.15000000000000002** (errors included) which leads to confusion as to what your true value is.

**The easiest fix :** Use `myNum.tofixed(2);` for two decimal places.

```
var a:String = "0.07";
var b:Number = 0.08;
trace( ( Number(a) + Number(b) ).toFixed(2) ); //gives 0.15
```

**The correct fix :** Use whole numbers (integers) & Divide by 100

```
var a:String = "7";
var b:Number = 8;
trace( ( Number(a) + Number(b) ) /100 ); //gives 0.15
```

Think of it like cents & dollars. Since you have three digits for **float** dollars as `1.75` that can be same as `175` in **integer** cents. To get the `1.75` from our integer cents we do `175 / 100 = 1.75`. Divide by 100 to get two decimal places, divide by 1000 for three decimal places and so on...
To add that fractined value back to a `Number` just do something like :

```
var myNum : Number = ( Number(a) + Number(b) ) /100;
trace("myNum : " + myNum); //gives myNum : 0.15
```

Comment: So the cure is like doctors say - "symptomatic"... Thans.